# plotting CSVs that are buried in different directories

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to dig through my computer and plot a bunch of CSVs on one plot (I'm using Python 2.7 and Pandas).

While all the CSV files have the same name of file.csv, they are located in a myriad of different folders. I've done the following below where I wrap the CSVs into a dataframe and then plot the dataframe from a certain range of values.

I would like to label each plot as the folder name (i.e. have the legend specify the folder directory that the CSV is located in)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import os


class do(object):


   def something(self):

     style.use('ggplot')

     file_1 = r'C:\User\me\PathABC\Folder123\file.csv'
     file_2 = r'C:\User\me\PathABC\Folder456\file.csv'
     file_3 = r'C:\User\me\PathABC\Folder789\file.csv'
     file_4 = r'C:\User\me\PathABC\Folder101112\file.csv'




     df1 = pd.read_csv(file_1,header=None)
     df2 = pd.read_csv(file_2,header=None)
     df3 = pd.read_csv(file_3,header=None)
     df4 = pd.read_csv(file_4,header=None)


     plt.plot(df1[0],df1[1],label='Folder123')
     plt.plot(df2[0],df2[1],label='Folder456')
     plt.plot(df3[0],df3[1],label='Folder789')
     plt.plot(df4[0],df4[1],label='Folder101112')


     plt.xlim([200000,800000])

     plt.legend()
     plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
     plt.xlabel('Hz')

     plt.grid(True,color='k')

     plt.show()


  x=do()
  x.something()
```

essentially, i would like to automate this process such that I can parse my computer by using the following logic:

```
where file.csv exists, plot it
label plot with folder name of where file.csv came from
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your class? It seems completely useless to me.

Comment: this is part of a much, much larger code...

Comment: Yeah, I still don't see the purpose of a class here. Regardless, do you have any idea where the files might be? Or are you going to have to walk your entire file-system? You don't really have a question here, it seems more like a request for someone to write code for you.

Comment: walk the entire folder system labeled 'me'. I could delete this if you think it's a bad question.

Comment: Have you looked up how to *walk* a file system in Python? Have you tried implementing a solution, and it failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory) by @pycruft and edited by @Martin Thoma. I would use `walk` to get the full path of all csv files existing in several folders inside a specific path as follows:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join,splitext
f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(specific_path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if splitext(filename)[1].upper() == '.CSV':
            f.extend([join(dirpath,filename)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Walking a file path is one answer, but you may be able to use `glob.glob` in simpler cases where the target folders are all at the same depth in the filesystem. For example,

```
for filename in glob.glob('somewhere/sheets/*/file.csv')
```

will iterate over all files called `file.csv` in any subfolder of `somewhere/sheets`. If they are all two levels down, `glob.glob('somewhere/sheets/*/*/file.csv')` will work, and if they are all one or two levels down, you can join the lists from two `glob` invocations.